# Unadvise a function (remove all advice from it)

Tags: advice

I cannot find a predefined command in `nadvice` to easily unadvise a function in Emacs 24.5.1.
Something like:

```el
(defun advice-unadvice (sym)
  "Remove all advices from symbol SYM."
  (interactive "aFunction symbol:")
  (advice-mapc `(lambda (fun props) (advice-remove ,(quote sym) fun)) sym))
```

Is there such a thing predefined?

Comment: I haven't come across a use case where you would need to interactively add/remove advices. Normally you put `advice-add` or `advice-remove` in a package or config and then forget about it.

Comment: @KaushalModi It is useful for trouble-shooting in the case that you have several modifications of a badly performing function and you want to see whether the original version does behave normally.

Comment: @KaushalModi: [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) provides a good use case, I think. It lets you dynamically add and remove any number of Isearch filter predicates (aka search filters) while searching incrementally. This means add/remove advice interactively - see [Dynamic Isearch Filtering](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicIsearchFiltering).

Comment: Another use case is if you (I did) added a lambda advice.

Answer (score 15):

```el
(defun advice-unadvice (sym)
  "Remove all advices from symbol SYM."
  (interactive "aFunction symbol: ")
  (advice-mapc (lambda (advice _props) (advice-remove sym advice)) sym))
```

Comment: Okay, this should also work. But, this is more like a comment and not an answer to the actual question.

Comment: Maybe the question was not clear enough. Then it is not your fault that you gave this comment as an answer.  I've edited my question to make it more clear. -- Thanks for the response!

Comment: I've [submitted a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-04/msg00754.html) to add `advice-remove-all` to `nadvice.el`.

Comment: A shame it hasn't been implemented.