# How to eliminate all advice from function?

Tags: advice

Is there a way to remove all advice added to a function with `advice-add`?

`advice-remove` requires the original function to be passed in. Sometimes, when experimenting w/ advice, I'll add several lambdas as advice to an fn, and would like a way to clear them all out.

Comment: How about this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24658/5296